# Make VSCode know about application built-ins

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I'm using python and [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) for scripting inside [ANSA](https://www.beta-cae.com/ansa.htm) and [VisIt](https://visit.llnl.gov/). These two applications both have built-in classes and functions/methods that Visual Studio Code cannot see. Therefore IntelliSense doesn't help me with calls to built-ins.

What is the recommended way to give Visual Studio Code information about built-in classes and functions/methods. In Typescript there is [`.d.ts`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html) files; is there anything similar for python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version ANSA 20 lets you import inbuilt function in to notepad++ please visit ANSA 20 help documents for details

Comment: Thank you very much for your information. For other tools I guess that I might have to write my own "declaration files".